# Taiwan tourist visa for Pakistani citizen

Tags: visas, pakistani-citizens, taiwan

I am a Pakistani citizen living in Pakistan and would like information about a Taiwan visa. I have checked [this website](http://www.boca.gov.tw/) but was unable to find any information for Pakistani citizens. There is obviously no Consulate or Embassy in Pakistan so:

1. What are the tourist visa requirements fora  Pakistani citizen from Pakistan?
2. Where can I lodge my application for a visa?

Comment: So, how about that bounty now ? :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### How to apply

Taiwan has an online visa application [system](https://visawebapp.boca.gov.tw/BOCA_MRVWeb/subroot/MRVWeb0_form.jsp) which lists Pakistan in the citizenship menu. They'll ask you where you want to apply for your visa, this means where you'll go for an interview (if applicable), present your documents and pick up your visa. They explain the process [here](http://www.boca.gov.tw/ct.asp?xItem=2365&ctNode=777&mp=2).

### Where to apply

The Taiwanese [missions](http://www.roc-taiwan.org/portalOfDiplomaticMission_en.html) in Asia nearest to you are in [India](http://www.roc-taiwan.org/in_en/index.html), but I'm assuming this might be problematic for you. There are others in the GCC countries ([Dubai](http://www.roc-taiwan.org/dxb_en/index.html), [Oman](http://www.roc-taiwan.org/om_en/index.html) or [Kuwait](http://www.roc-taiwan.org/kw_en/index.html) look closest to you), although as a Pakistani citizen you need a visa just to get to these places. None of these consulates have mention of any jurisdiction, so you could very possibly apply there.

As an alternative, Turkey (which also hosts a Taiwanese mission) might be a bit easier because they have an eVisa [system](https://www.evisa.gov.tr/en/).

Another alternative, as JonathanReez mentioned, is a visa agency in Pakistan that can represent you so you don't have to travel, however if Taiwan requests a physical presence (interview for example) they'll be of limited assistance.

### Requirements

As for the requirements of the visa, you'll find them all listed [here](https://www.boca.gov.tw/content.asp?mp=2&CuItem=1900) or [here](http://www.boca.gov.tw/ct.asp?xItem=1422&ctNode=777&mp=2). You'll need:

> - A passport valid for at least six months;
> - A duly completed application form with two photos taken within the past six months;
> - An outbound airline ticket or verifiable proof of purchase of steamship ticket ;
> - Documents verifying the purpose of visit;
> - Other relevant documents.
> - A visa fee of 50 or 100USD (single or multiple-entry)

Comment: OP might also be able to do it through a local visa agency, rather than traveling to the consulate in person.

Comment: From reading online, it appears that most Pakistanis get Taiwan visas in Saudi Arabia or Hong Kong.

Comment: Kuwait is out as Pakistan (and 6 other nationalities) are banned from visa issuance; so Saudi Arabia seems the likely source.

Comment: How sure are you that the links in the "Where to apply" links are trustworthy? They don't go to the usual *.gov.tw domain, but to *.roc-taiwan.org which is registered through an domain registration anonymizer in Florida. That's not the way government websites usually operate.